# Best way to setup CI/CD pipeline with dedicated database for each instance (branch) - Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, azure-devops, continuous-integration

So, we have the following setup right now.

We have project "web-api" setup (Docker Compose). That project connects to another project "Netbox" (also Docker Compose) which has the main database.

In our "web-api" we currently have a CI/CD pipeline i Azure, where we run linting, test and deployment on our main branch.

But we need to setup a pipeline to run each time a new branch is pushed. Meaning we need to run tests up against the "Netbox" with it's database. So in case we need to run three individual instances of our branch pipeline we need three individual "Netbox" instances as well.

So to make it scaleable and easy to maintain we was considering to put Netbox in Kubernetes with 3 replicas. Like in the chart below.

[image]

Now, my question is: We need to make sure that each branch has it's own dedicated Netbox instance. Otherwise our tests we write to the same database and that wouldn't work. Is that possible to do with Kubernetes or doesn't it make sense? -if not what would make most sense to do in this scenario?

Comment: It's definitely possible; in the deployment system I work on, database dependencies like this can be expressed as Helm chart dependencies, for example, and each test build gets a separate in-cluster database.  Have you tried this already?  Is there a specific technical problem you're running into?

Comment: No, we haven't tried it yet. We just want to do some research before we build, as we are developers and not so much devops engineers :-). 

So what we're mostly puzzled about is how do we ensure that each netbox instace only receive requests from one pipeline instance because all request from pipeline instances will come from same external IP. -it might be something obvious that Kubernetes just does when you eg. deploy it as StatefulSet.

Comment: Not fully following your use case but for example you can put each replica on a K8s cluster into its own namespace and assign a different host name to it configured via ingress. If you can then make each pipeline use its corresponding hostname, i.e. mybranch.myhost.com - this would handle the routing issue. Hope it makes sense based on your use case because we usually advocate for trunk-based development and single processing for each branch.